# How to remove the prefix from each element of python list?

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a python list with items as follows:

```
[ 1.1 ] 1. a electronic bill presentment system.
[ 1.2 ] a network.
[ 1.3 ] a plurality of first stations, each associated with a respective one of a plurality of users and operable to transmit first requests for bills of its associated user via the network.
[ 1.4 ] a central network station configured to receive the transmitted first requests for bills and to transmit, responsive to each of the received first requests, bill availability information for the associated user via the network, wherein each of the plurality of first stations is configured to receive the transmitted bill availability information for its associated user and is operable to transmit second requests for bills of its associated user via the network.
[ 1.5 ] a plurality of second network stations, each associated with a respective one of a plurality of billers, configured to receive the transmitted second requests for bills and to transmit, responsive thereto, the requested bills of the associated user via the network.
[ 1.6 ] wherein the bill availability information for the associated user identifies those of the plurality of billers having a bill available for that user without identifying an amount of the bill of each of the identified billers for the associated user.
[ 2.1 ] 2. a method for presenting electronic bills.
[ 2.2 ] storing, at a plurality of different locations, electronic bills of a plurality of different billers for a plurality of different users.
[ 2.3 ] storing identifiers of the stored electronic bills at a location different than the plurality of different locations.
[ 2.4 ] transmitting a first request for the stored electronic bills for a first of the plurality of users.
[ 2.5 ] transmitting one or more of the stored identifiers of the stored electronic bills for the first user responsive to the transmitted first request, each of the transmitted one or more identifiers being associated with a respective one of the stored electronic bills of a different one of the plurality of billers.
[ 2.6 ] transmitting a second request for at least one of the stored electronic bills identified by the transmitted one or more identifiers.
[ 2.7 ] transmitting the at least one identified stored electronic bill responsive to the transmitted second request.
[ 2.8 ] wherein the transmitted one or more identifiers identifies the stored electronic bills without identifying an amount of the identified stored electronic bills.
```

All i need is to remove the prefix from each items but don't know how to remove this.

For example,

I need to remove `[2.8](space) [2.7](space)`. Each new line print of above represent the items of list.
Also like `[ 1.1 ] 1. a electronic bill presentment system.`, i need to remove `[ 1.1 ] 1.`

My code function to remove as below, i am using a logic to first split using space and then remove non-alpha values.

But it is not working properly.

Please help.

```
TextDictionaryValuesList = list(TextDictionary.values()) 
# You can make a test list using above given items of mylist

def remove_non_alpha(splitlist):
    for j in range(0, len(splitlist)):
        if(splitlist[j].isalpha()):
            splitlist[j] = splitlist[j]
        else:
            splitlist[j] = ""       

    return splitlist


for i in range(0, len(TextDictionaryValuesList)):

    print(TextDictionaryValuesList[i])

    splitlist = TextDictionaryValuesList[i].split(" ")
    splitlist = remove_non_alpha(splitlist)
    TextDictionaryValuesList[i] = splitlist

print(TextDictionaryValuesList)
```

Comment: This looks like a classroom/assignment question. Are you familiar with regular expressions?

Comment: yes i know reg expression but the thing is not able to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re
l = ['[ 1.1 ] 1. a electronic bill presentment system.','[ 1.2 ] a network.']

[re.sub(r'\[\s*\d+\.*\d*\s*\]\s+(?:\d+\.\s*)?', '', s) for s in l]
# ['a electronic bill presentment system.', 'a network.']
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JVPUbx/3)

---

Testing with a larger list of strings:

```
l = ['[ 1.1 ] 1. a electronic bill presentment system.',\
'[ 1.2 ] a network.',\
'[ 1.3 ] a plurality of first stations, each associated with a respective one of a plurality of users and operable to transmit first requests for bills of its associated user via the network.',\
'[ 1.5 ] a plurality of second network stations, each associated with a respective one of a plurality of billers, configured to receive the transmitted second requests for bills and to transmit, responsive thereto, the requested bills of the associated user via the network.',\
'[ 1.6 ] wherein the bill availability information for the associated user identifies those of the plurality of billers having a bill available for that user without identifying an amount of the bill of each of the identified billers for the associated user.',\
'[ 2.1 ] 2. a method for presenting electronic bills.']

[re.sub(r'\[\s*\d+\.*\d*\s*\]\s+(?:\d+\.\s*)?', '', s) for s in l]

['a electronic bill presentment system.',
 'a network.',
 'a plurality of first stations, each associated with a respective one of a plurality of users and operable to transmit first requests for bills of its associated user via the network.',
 'a plurality of second network stations, each associated with a respective one of a plurality of billers, configured to receive the transmitted second requests for bills and to transmit, responsive thereto, the requested bills of the associated user via the network.',
 'wherein the bill availability information for the associated user identifies those of the plurality of billers having a bill available for that user without identifying an amount of the bill of each of the identified billers for the associated user.',
 'a method for presenting electronic bills.']
```

Comment: is this link automatically create Reg exp https://regex101.com/r/JVPUbx/1

Comment: No, this is used to test a regex on a sample string @RinkuYadav

Comment: I'm curious about the quantifiers used. I would use `+` for decimals and `*` for spaces. I would change at least `\d?`

Comment: Fair point @Adirio `*` does make more sense here giving it a second thought. It was simply because there seems to be 1 space at most in all cases

Comment: @yatu what if i want to remove just the `1. ` after `]` in `[ 1.1 ] 1. `, what could be the regular expression and only kept `[ 1.1 ]`

Answer (score 2):

You should regular expression to substitute the pattern with an empty string

```
>>> re.sub(r'\[\s?\d\.\d\s?]\s?(\d(\.\s)?)?', '', '[ 1.1 ] 1. a electronic bill presentment system.')
'a electronic bill presentment system.'
```

Comment: As shown in the answer, this does not remove the leading 1. after the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

data = ["[ 1.1 ] 1. a electronic bill presentment system.","[ 1.2 ] a network."]

result = [re.search('[a-z,A-Z].*',i).group(0) for i in data]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to avoid regex, you can keep it simple as this as long you don't have fancy prefix like `[1.2.b]` or anything with letters.

```
def chop_non_alpha(txt):
    for i in range(len(txt)):
        if txt[i].isalpha():
            return txt[i:]

for line in lines:
    print(chop_non_alpha(line))
```